# Weblogic Performance Tunning

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, server-administration

We have a problem with Weblogic 10.3.2. We install a standard domain with default parameters. In this domain we only have a managed server and only running a web application on this managed server. 
After installation we face performance problems. Sometimes user waits 1-2 minutes for application responses. (Forexample user clicks a button and it takes 1-2 minutes to perform GUI refresh. Its not a complicated task.)

To overcome these performance problems define parameters like;

- configuraion->server start->arguments

> -Xms4g -Xmx6g -Dweblogic.threadpool.MinPoolSize=100 -Dweblogic.threadpool.MaxPoolSize=500

And also we change the datasource connection pool parameters of the application in the weblogic side as below.

> - Initial Capacity:50
> - Maximum Capacity:250
> - Capacity Increment: 10
> - Statement Cache Type: LRU
> - Statement Cache Size: 50

We run Weblogic on 32 GB RAM servers with 16 CPUs. %25 resource of the server machine is dedicated for the Weblogic. But we still have performance problem.

Our target is servicing 300-400 concurrent users avoiding 1-2 minutes waiting time for each application request.

- Defining a work manager can solve performance issue?
- My datasource or managed bean definition is incorrect?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks for your replies

Comment: Is everything good at your db side?? can you please let me know from console.. how many active jdbc connections you have at any given time??